# Disable default popover in showmoreclick in full calendar v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar V6 library in react.js click on moreLinkClick. Popover appears on the screen I want to disable the popover, to perform some other action.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible currently.  https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features